# Steam not letting me sell items

Tags: steam

Recently I added money to my steam wallet using my Visa card. Now on all my marketable items it says:

> You've recently funded your steam wallet using PayPal or an unverified payment method that has had a recent increase in use. You'll be unable to use the market for a few days while the funds are verified. If nothing further occurs you'll be able to use the community market on 12/30/14 11 AM

This has never happened before and Visa is a verified payment method. Is this a problem that other people have faced or is it just me?

Comment: Have you added money to Steam using that specific Visa card before?

Answer (score 1):

This a problem that other people have faced. I have recently had the same issue on my dads steam account. That only happens if you change your payment method and it only applies to the Market, not the Store.

Comment: I haven't changed my payment method though....

Comment: Was it another visa card?

Comment: No I use two occasionally my friend uses his on my account (I give him the items he buys)but I use mine and his almost equally because we're roommates